# Added stored procedure in database, how to get in EF Context?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I did a database-first approach with Entity Framework, so I basically created a data model object, set the connection string, and the `.edmx`, context, and all related files were created in an instance. When I put right click the edmx file in designer mode, and click update model from database, it doesn't update the context. I have a new stored procedure in the database I want to show in the context, how can I get it in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the update model from database, it should let you choose which database objects (stored procedures, functions, tables, etc.) you want to add/remove/refresh.

1. right click in the edmx designer, click update model from database
2. click next
3. you should see a screen that says "choose your database objects and settings"
   there should be a "stored procedures and functions" category for you to add the new SP from

Comment: Yes I did that, however in the output it says C:\MyProject\Data\EF\procTest_Result.cs could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (restart VS)
If that doesn't work, try making sure that your VS is updated to the latest version.

Comment: hm I don't know if b/c project is binded to tfs, but after checking in from Data.tt, it appeared in context.cs, very quirky.

Comment: TFS can be a royal PITA

Comment: LOL yeah, doesn't seem to play nicely with EF tools.

Comment: Are you using an internal TFS or Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Internal, you prefer one over the other?

Comment: I was just going to say that if you're using VS online, you have the option of using something simpler like GIT rather than TFS. It has been a while since I used internal TFS so I don't really have much to say about it.